# Return the range of indices of a dict within a list, by matching the dict's value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. I can access the index of the list of the dictionary that contains the 'name' I am looking for like this:

```
next(index for (index, d) in enumerate(lst) if d["name"] == "Joe")
```

But what if "Joe" occurs in multiple dictionaries throughout my list? In other words there will be a range of indices of my list that have a dictionary containing the name "Joe".

How can I return that range of indices?

Comment: Change it to a list comprehension. `[index for (index, d) in enumerate(lst) if d["name"] == "Joe"]`. You will get all the `index`es where the dictionary's `name` is `Joe`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Add as answer if you want the point.